# Extend window class

Tags: javascript, class, window

I would like to extend window class as

```
window.Physics = class Physics extends window.Trait
```

But it crashes with

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: window.Physics is not a constructor

EDIT: Trait.js

```
window.Trait = class Trait {
constructor(name) {
    this.NAME = name;
...
```

Comment: what's window.Trait?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create Class Physics with a constructor just like a Trait and then you can extend Physics. It's impossible to do without a constructor.

You can read about class inheritance here
https://javascript.info/class-inheritance

Comment: @Atalyk, I've just edited my answer. You can check the link

Comment: I mean I need to attach it to window

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just:

```
window.Physics = class extends Trait {
     // Your code here
}
```